# Looping through HTML table and store td values as a string using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have following table

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
{
    $id=$row['product_id'];
    $name=$row['name'];
    $stock=$row['stock'];
    ?>
    <tbody>
    <tr   >
        <td class="edit_td">
            <span id="first_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $name; ?></span>
        </td>
        <td class="edit_td">
            <span id="last_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php if($stock==0){echo 0;}else{echo $stock;} ?></span>
        </td>
        <td class="edit_td1" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-3 inputContainer">
                    <input class="form-control cls-quantity" id="quanti_<?php echo $id; ?>" name="number" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="action_td" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="cursor:pointer;color:red;"></span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php
}
?>
```

And button:

`<a href="customer_details.php?shop=<?php echo $_GET['shop'];?>" class="btn btn-info" role="button" onclick="return td_validation();store_value_as_string();">Generate Bill</a>`

**Question:** Here I want to return a function `store_value_as_string();` after `td_validation();` which loop through all `<tr>` and get `id` of `class="edit_td1"` and associated value of `id="quanti_<?php echo $id; ?>"`. Then function `store_value_as_string();` will gives me two strings

`str1 = 121,122,123,124;//id of class="edit_td1"`

`str2 = 2,3,1,4;//associated value of id="quanti_<?php echo $id; ?>"`

these two strings are required for ajax call(pass to other php page).
I actually have code for doing same but it runs `onchange` of `".edit_td1"` but the sequence of operations by -->tester<-- i.e. `onchange-blur(leave the textbox for same <tr> -onchange-blure-onchange...` gives me wrong output.

Table look likes:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna use the [Jquery each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Iterate over all td's with the class '.edit_td1'. Fetch their id's using .attr('id') and add to an array as well and then later use Jquery's Array join to get your desired output of str1.

For str2 with each loop, find input with the class '.cls-quantity' and get its value. Add that number to a list and then again use Array.join.

I hope my code works fine. Haven't debugged it.

```
function store_value_as_string(){
  var array1= new Array();
  var array2 = new Array();
  $('td.edit_td1').each(function(index, element){

    //Not sure if we need this line. 
    //Might need if we dont get the element in function's argument 
    //var element = this;

    array1.push($(element).attr('id'));


   //find might return an array so can use this line. I have not debugged it.
  array2.push($(element).find('input.cls-quantity')[0].val())
  //array2.push($(element).find('input.cls-quantity').val());
  });
 var str1 =  array1.join(',');
 var str2 =  array2.join(',');
}
```

Comment: I think your  $('td.edit_td1').each(function(element) doesn't reach because function store_value_as_string() executes but alert(str1);
  alert(str2);
  alert(array1);
  alert(array2); didn't executes

Comment: in  function store_value_as_string(){alert("hi");//executes then, {--your code--},then alert("end");//doesn't executes. How?

Comment: I think our problem is in $('td.edit_td1').each(function(element) because alert(element) alerts 0 .

Comment: did you try using 'this' keyword instead of element as mentioned in the comments section?

Comment: alert(this) = [objectHTMLTableCellElement]

Comment: I have updated my answer. We need to add index to each's callback or we can use 'this' keyword. Also element or 'this' keyword becomes a javascript variable. I changed them to Jquery variables so i can use val() and find() on them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89238/discussion-between-imab-asghar-and-vilas-galave).